# facebook api video parameters

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I search in Facebook documentation about since and until parameter but I didn't find something 
Here I wanted to try to do

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/1017313271664514/videos?fields=reactions.limit(0).summary(true),comments.limit(0).summary(true),type,link,full_picture,description,created_time,length&limit=100&access_token=XXXXX|XXXXXXX&until=1538050674&since=1537964274
```

it returns me an empty array ... seems until and since doesn't work 
IS there a solution to limit ?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn’t use the exact same value for since and until? Maybe there is no video that has a creation time that falls exactly into this zero-second “interval” …?

Comment: @misorude I  have checked and there is video for this period

Comment: No sure if you can call _zero_ seconds difference between start and end a “period” even. (Plus, did you take time zone into account?) Try with a greater interval first - say, from one day earlier to one day later, and see if you get results then.

Comment: Does `access_token=XXXXX|XXXXXXX` mean you are using just your app access token? Then you would have to get your app reviewed for the Page Public Content Access feature first. Use a user access token or a page access token.

Comment: @misorude my access token works well I am using it for other request 
even I change the period it stills return me a empty array

Comment: Try the request in Graph API Explorer and see if you get any debug messages there. And be more detailed in your description of what you are actually doing - “I am using it for other request” could mean a lot of things. Again, with an app access token you should not even be able to access most page data (unless you already got PPCA approved), even if you have admin access to the page.